# POSIX message queues folder

Tags: ipc, mqueue

I've been working remotely with POSIX message queues for some days. Now I want to do it in my own PC but I've found that there's no /dev/mqueue folders where queues are created; which means that I don't know where they are (of whether there are or not), so I can't access there to delete them in case of an unexpected end of my program.

I notice my code is not running properly due to 'zombie' queues, but I can't remove them from that folder as I do with semaphores and shared memories (hosted in /dev/shm).

I suspect that some configuration about this can be done with the following command, but I'd like to be aware of what I am doing before changing anything.

```
mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
```

I hope I've managed to show you my problem, so that someone can give me a solution.

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# mkdir /dev/mqueue
# mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
```

Source:
[Linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview)